# Is the solution of every differential equation CONTINUOUS in it's given domain?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

I am a first reader of Differential Equation. I was solving a differential equation whose solution is $|f(x)|= c$. Now my question is can I write that the solution is $f(x)= k$. If $f(x)$ is continuous then I can  remove the mod.

But I am not sure whether the function $f(x)$ is continuous or not. (Here $c$ and $k$ are constants)

So that's why my question is the following.
 Is the solution of every differential equation CONTINUOUS  in it's given domain?

Can anyone please help me to understand this?

Comment: I'd worry more about such a thing being differentiable.

Comment: If the original equation is something like $y'=F(y,t)$, then $y$ must be differentiable, and thus continuous.

Answer (score 2):

As you know a differentiable function in continuous.

A solution to a differential equation $y'= f(x,y)$ is a function $y=y(x)$ which satisfy $$ y'(x) = f(x,y(x))$$

That is the solution $y=y(x)$ is necessarily  differentiable  and its derivative satisfies   $$ y'(x) = f(x,y(x))$$

In your example of |f(x)|=c, you need an initial condition to make a decision about f(x)=c or f(x)=-c but in either case your function should be continuous on the given domain.

Comment: No I do not know whether it is c or -c. That's why I suppose it as an another constant k.@Mohammad Riazi-Kermani

Comment: That is a good idea. With the constant k, it is clear that $f(x)=k$ is continuous.

Comment: If I can not write in this form --$$ y'(x) = f(x,y(x))$$..Then what would happen?@Mohammad Riazi-Kermani

Comment: Then you have what is called an implicit solution. In any case the solution is continuous.

Comment: In either case, $f(x)=f(x_0)$ in the given situation. This avoids the discussion on $c$, $-c$, $k$ by directly using the initial condition at some $x_0$.

Comment: I did not get you @LutzL  Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Will that implicit solution be continuous on $\mathbb R^2$ if no domain is mentioned? @Mohammad Riazi-Kermani

Comment: $0=F(x,y,y')$ is an implicit ODE on the domain where the derivative $F_y$ does not vanish. Per definition, as a solution is a continuously differentiable function, any solution is also continuous.

Comment: Your last comment is too complicated to understand for me@LutzL